# All date output bug between two dates

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, localdate

This is a method that prints out all dates between two dates.
But as the year goes by, the December part is going to add another year. 
There's an bug.

It's a Korean date.
Sorry for the translator.

```
String startDate = "2019-12-23";
String endDate = "2020-01-01";

LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse(startDate);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse(endDate).plusDays(1);
List<String> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
    .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
    .map(date -> date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());


System.err.println(dates);
```

bug: [20191223, 20191224, 20191225, 20191226, 20191227, 20191228, ***20201229, 20201230, 20201231***, 20200101]

Comment: why 20201229, 20201230, 20201231 ??

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @shmosel All dates between 2019-12-23 and 2020-01-01 must be obtained. But from 2019-12-29, the year will be 2020.

Comment: So it's a bug, not an error.

Comment: @shmosel I'm sorry. I've revised my writing.

Comment: not use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd")`. use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")`.

Comment: There is subtle difference between "YYYY" and "yyyy". Although they both represents year but "yyyy" represents the calendar year and "YYYY" represents year of the week. For example year of the week of the date 2019-12-29 will be 2020 as it comes in the next year of week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `BASIC_ISO_DATE` and it will fix your problem

```
List<String> dates = Stream.iterate(start, date -> date.plusDays(1))
                .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end))
                .map(date -> date.format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());


System.err.println(dates);
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect.
I won't forget to answer my first question.